# Alertblock and Beamer Frame Spacing

Tags: beamer

This slide is showing compiling errors. I guess there isn't enough space. My question : 
a) Why isn't align working inside the alert block?
b) Why isn't allowframebreaks working in my particular slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\title[L]{Blah}
\subtitle{Lectur} 
\author{Some Random Guy} 
\institute[L]{L}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\useoutertheme{tree}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue!30,fg=black}
%\setbeamercolor{alertblock title}{bg=red!30,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*   {2em}\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{4em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection\par}
\newcommand{\bbeta}[1]{\boldsymbol\beta_{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}
\newcommand{\undset}[2]{\underset{\scriptscriptstyle #1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\by}[1]{\mathbf Y_{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}
\newcommand{\bx}[1]{\mathbf x_{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}
\newcommand{\beps}[1]{\boldsymbol\epsilon_{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}
%\setbeamercolor {item}{fg=red}
%\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red} %\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=blue}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{
\def\@listi{\leftmargin3em
  \topsep 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2.5\p@
  \parsep 0\p@
  \itemsep3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus3\p@}
}


\begin{document}


\section{Covariance matrix}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Strategy - Start with the Covariance}
\begin{itemize}
\item We can use the shortcut formula $\sigma_{Y_1Y_2}=E[Y_1Y_2]-E[Y_1]E[Y_2]$.
\item Recall $E[Y_1]=2/3$ from our previous lecture.
\item You should easily be able to verify that $E[Y_2]=4/3$.
\item \begin{alertblock}
\begin{align*}
E[Y_1] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y_1 f(y_1,y_2) dy_1 dy_2 \\
 & =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y_1 f_1(y_1) dy_1
\end{align*}
\end{alertblock}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}**strong text**
```

The error is  - ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\end #1->\csname end#1
\endcsname \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@e...
l.176 \end{frame}

Comment: Do you mean `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]\frametitle{Strategy - Start with the Covariance}`?

Comment: yes! I used the shortcut method of writing Frametitle

Comment: Please post a **complete** example beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Compilable (or, in this case, non-compilable) code is much more useful than mere fragments. In any case, if I complete it myself, your code compiles fine. You need to show us what generates the error.

Comment: Done! Sorry about that!

Comment: Hmmm... Did you change the frame, too? The problem is the `alertblock`. Do you really need an item bullet, a block and an `align*` environment here?! They don't seem fully compatible (either in reality or in my imagination - what *should* the result look like if it worked?). Note: I don't mean your customisation of the template for this causes problems - the error occurs with the default template, as well.

Comment: `alertblock` needs an argument, the title of the block.

Comment: Additionally, I would write the `alertblock` outside the itemize.

Comment: @Dox -- That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Dox, Jesse  - the item environment works usually given the complication. And I guess you guys are right about the itemize. I don't need the alert block within the itemize.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `alertblock` needs an argument, the title of the block.